# Error while installing new rails new generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Just installed Ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.6 and getting this error when using rails server command

```
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:43:in `pick': Couldn't find handler for: thin, puma, webrick. (LoadError)
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:59:in `default'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in `print_boot_information'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Documents/ruby/webapp/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/Documents/ruby/webapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Documents/ruby/webapp/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with the same versions (Rails 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.3.0p0), which means that you probably haven't provided enough detail for someone to help. What OS are you on? What params did you pass to `rails new`?

Comment: can you put more details. like can you paste your Gemfile here or other userful information.

Comment: What was the exact command you used? How did you create the app upfront? What it an existing application that was working with another version combination of Ruby and Rails? Or did you create a new app?

Comment: I reverted back to ruby 2.2.2 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install node.js ?
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nodejs

Comment: I get `nodejs is already the newest version (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4).` and the error is still there. Cook node.js from scratch?